# Horse Racing Simulation Loop

Tags: python, loops

So I have this program that basically runs a horse betting simulation. When the user chooses the horse from a list of names I have created, my program returns a % that predicts the horse's chances of winning the race (I am still working on this so just don't mind it). However, the program asks the user if they want to change horses. If they do, they get to choose their horse again, if not, the program continues to the race. I want to make my program so that it only allows the user to change horses once to make it a gamble. Is there a way I can do that? If there are any other changes that should be made let me know! (Created in Python).

code:

```
import random 
import time 




# percentage for the chosen horse to win the race
def Percent(): 
    min = 1 
    max = 100 
    win = random.randint(min, max) 
    print(win) 

# asks user if they want to change their chosen horse
def Horserestart():
    new_horse = input("Do you wan to change you horse? Type Y or N. ")
    if new_horse == "Y":
        Horse()
    elif new_horse == "N":
        New()

# user chooses a horse
def Horse(): 
    print("Horses to bet on: Tyrone, Jamal, Jaquavious, Quandale, Quantavious, and Charlie.") 
    horse_pick = input("What horse do you want to choose? ") 
    if horse_pick == "Tyrone": 
        option = print("You chose Tyrone, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        Horserestart() 
    elif horse_pick == "Jamal": 
        option = print("You chose Jamal, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        Horserestart() 
    elif horse_pick == "Jaquavious": 
        option = print("You chose Jaquavious, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        Horserestart() 
    elif horse_pick == "Quandale": 
        option = print("You chose Quandale, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        Horserestart() 
    elif horse_pick == "Quantavious": 
        option = print("You chose Quantavious, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        Horserestart() 
    elif horse_pick == "Charlie": 
        option = print("You chose Charlie, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        Horserestart()

# user inputs their total money and bet amount
def New():
    while True:
        total_money = int(input("What is the total amount of money you have? ")) 
        goal = total_money * 2 
        if total_money < 10: 
            print("Sorry but that is too low, please input a higher amount.") 
            Horserestart() 
        elif total_money > 10: 
            print("Your goal is $",goal,"to reach.")
        bet_amount = int(input("What is the amount you want to bet on? ")) 
        bet_total = total_money - bet_amount 
        print("You will bet $",bet_amount,". You now have $",bet_total," left to bet with. ")
        print("The race will start in:") 
        Race()

# race countdown
def Race():
    time_sec = 10 
    while time_sec: 
        mins, secs = divmod(time_sec, 60) 
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs) 
        print(timeformat, end='\r') 
        time.sleep(1) 
        time_sec -= 1 
    print("..........THE RACE HAS STARTED..........") 
    Mech_race() 
 
# functino of the race (not completed)
def Mech_race(): 
    horse1 = "Tyrone" 
    horse2 = "Jamal" 
    horse3 = "Jaquavious" 
    horse4 = "Quandale" 
    horse5 = "Quantavious" 
    horse6 = "Charlie" 
    horses = [horse1, horse2, horse3, horse4, horse5, horse6]
    random_horse = random.choice(horses)
    random_horse1 = random.choice(horses) 
    random_horse2 = random.choice(horses) 
    random_horse3 = random.choice(horses) 
    random_horse4 = random.choice(horses)
    random_horse5 = random.choice(horses)
    random_horse6 = random.choice(horses)
    random_horse7 = random.choice(horses)
    random_horse8 = random.choice(horses)
    random_horse9 = random.choice(horses)
    if random_horse is horse1: 
        print(horse1,"has taken the lead!") 
    else: 
        print(random_horse,"has taken the lead!") 

    for positions in range(10):
        overtakes = "overtakes"
        trips = "trips"
        falls_behind = "falls behind"
        gaining = " is gaining on"
        takes = "takes"
        positions = [overtakes, trips, falls_behind, gaining, takes]
        place = random.choice(positions)
        if place is overtakes:
            print(random_horse,"overtakes",random_horse1)
        elif place is trips:
            print(random_horse2,"trips",random_horse3)
        elif place is falls_behind:
            print(random_horse4,"falls behind",random_horse5)
        elif place is gaining:
            print(random_horse6,"gains on",random_horse7)
        elif place is takes:
            print(random_horse8,"takes",random_horse9,"position")

# introduction to the program/race
def Main(): 
    print("Hello and welcome to the Sussy Baka horse race! ") 
    user_name = input("What is your name? ") 
    print("Hello",user_name,"this is when you choose your horse and your bet. ") 
    Horse() 

Main()
```

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library.

Answer (score 0):

You could paste the code for the Horserestart function anywhere Horserestart() is in the code.

```
def Horse(): 
    print("Horses to bet on: Tyrone, Jamal, Jaquavious, Quandale, Quantavious, and Charlie.") 
    horse_pick = input("What horse do you want to choose? ") 
    if horse_pick == "Tyrone": 
        option = print("You chose Tyrone, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        new_horse = input("Do you wan to change you horse? Type Y or N. ")
        if new_horse == "Y":
            Horse()
        elif new_horse == "N":
            New()
```

You could also add a counter.

```
horse_restart = 0


def Horserestart():
    new_horse = input("Do you wan to change you horse? Type Y or N. ")
    if new_horse == "Y":
        horse_restart += 1
        Horse()
    elif new_horse == "N":
        New()

def Horse(): 
    print("Horses to bet on: Tyrone, Jamal, Jaquavious, Quandale, Quantavious, and Charlie.") 
    horse_pick = input("What horse do you want to choose? ") 
    if horse_pick == "Tyrone": 
        option = print("You chose Tyrone, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        if(horse_restart < 1):
            Horserestart()
```

OR

```
horse_restart = False


def Horserestart():
    new_horse = input("Do you wan to change you horse? Type Y or N. ")
    if new_horse == "Y":
        horse_restart = True
        Horse()
    elif new_horse == "N":
        New()

def Horse(): 
    print("Horses to bet on: Tyrone, Jamal, Jaquavious, Quandale, Quantavious, and Charlie.") 
    horse_pick = input("What horse do you want to choose? ") 
    if horse_pick == "Tyrone": 
        option = print("You chose Tyrone, your chances of winning are: ") 
        Percent() 
        if(horse_restart == False):
            Horserestart()
```